# Make Xcode warn about adding nullable properties to arrays or dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to make Xcode issue a warning for code like:

```
// Model.h

@interface Model : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, nullable) NSString *value;

@end

// Model.m

@implementation Model

@end

// ViewController.m

@implementation ViewController

- (void)test {

    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *values = [NSMutableArray array];

    Model *model = [Model new];

    [values addObject:model.value];
}

@end
```

?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible in Objective-C.

Not an actual warning, but the static analyzer will pick it up if it knows for sure that it would be `nil`, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = NSMutableArray.array;
NSString *string = nil;
[array addObject:string]; // Argument to 'NSMutableArray' method 'addObject:' cannot be nil
```

Comment: Bummer. I thought it should pick it up in my example too, as the static analyzer checks every possible code path already. And marking a property as `nullable` should have told it that there is a case in which that property could be `nil`.